# The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, stored-procedure

Tengo un procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server y me pide paramentros para editar los valore, en ASP.Net tengo un proyecto en capas, donde la capa datos tiene el siguiente codigo:

```
public string Editar(D_Cliente cliente)
    {
        string RPT = "";
        using (SqlConnection CON = D_Coneccion.Coneccion())
        {
            try
            {
                CON.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = CON;
                cmd.CommandText = "SP_Editar_Cliente";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                SqlParameter ParIDCliente = new SqlParameter();
                ParIDCliente.ParameterName = "@IDCliente";
                ParIDCliente.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                ParIDCliente.Value = cliente.ID_Cliente;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParIDCliente);

                SqlParameter ParIDEmpleado = new SqlParameter();
                ParIDEmpleado.ParameterName = "@IDEmpleado";
                ParIDEmpleado.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                ParIDEmpleado.Value = cliente.ID_Cliente;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParIDCliente);

                SqlParameter ParNombres = new SqlParameter();
                ParNombres.ParameterName = "@Nombres";
                ParNombres.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                ParNombres.Size = 250;
                ParNombres.Value = cliente.Nombres;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParNombres);

                SqlParameter ParApellidos = new SqlParameter();
                ParApellidos.ParameterName = "@Apellidos";
                ParApellidos.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                ParApellidos.Size = 250;
                ParApellidos.Value = cliente.Apellidos;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParApellidos);

                SqlParameter ParCorreo = new SqlParameter();
                ParCorreo.ParameterName = "@Correo";
                ParCorreo.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                ParCorreo.Size = 100;
                ParCorreo.Value = cliente.Correo;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParCorreo);


                SqlParameter ParEdad = new SqlParameter();
                ParEdad.ParameterName = "@Edad";
                ParEdad.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
                ParEdad.Value = cliente.Edad;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParEdad);


                SqlParameter ParTelefono = new SqlParameter();
                ParTelefono.ParameterName = "@Telefono";
                ParTelefono.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                ParTelefono.Size = 50;
                ParTelefono.Value = cliente.Telefono;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParTelefono);

                SqlParameter ParPais = new SqlParameter();
                ParPais.ParameterName = "@Pais ";
                ParPais.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                ParPais.Size = 50;
                ParPais.Value = cliente.Pais;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParPais);


                SqlParameter ParEstado_Departamento = new SqlParameter();
                ParEstado_Departamento.ParameterName = "@Estado_Departamento";
                ParEstado_Departamento.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                ParEstado_Departamento.Size = 50;
                ParEstado_Departamento.Value = cliente.Estado_Departamento;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParEstado_Departamento);


                SqlParameter ParDireccion = new SqlParameter();
                ParDireccion.ParameterName = "@Direccion";
                ParDireccion.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                ParDireccion.Size = 100;
                ParDireccion.Value = cliente.Direccion;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParDireccion);

                SqlParameter ParPasaporte = new SqlParameter();
                ParPasaporte.ParameterName = "@Pasaporte";
                ParPasaporte.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                ParPasaporte.Size = 150;
                ParPasaporte.Value = cliente.Pasaporte;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParPasaporte);


                SqlParameter ParDUI = new SqlParameter();
                ParDUI.ParameterName = "@DUI";
                ParDUI.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                ParDUI.Size = 10;
                ParDUI.Value = cliente.DUI;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParDUI);

                SqlParameter ParUsuario = new SqlParameter();
                ParUsuario.ParameterName = "@Usuario";
                ParUsuario.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                ParUsuario.Size = 50;
                ParUsuario.Value = cliente.Usuario;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParUsuario);

                SqlParameter ParContraseña = new SqlParameter();
                ParContraseña.ParameterName = "@Contrasena";
                ParContraseña.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
                ParContraseña.Size = 50;
                ParContraseña.Value = cliente.Contraseña;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ParContraseña);

                RPT = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1 ? "OK" : "No se edito el registro";
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                RPT = err.Message;
            }
            finally { CON.Close(); }

            return RPT;
        }
    }
```

Esto devulve el string y luego lo uso para saber si me ha devuelto un ok o un error, me funciona bien en Windows Form y WPF, pero al momento de ejecutarlo en ASP.Net core me da el error: The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection. La manera en la que lo ejecuto es usando una clase que obtiene parametros, son los que necesito para editar en la base de datos, en la vista paso los valores a la clase con un ASP-For y el nombre del parametro, luego en el controlador mando a llamar el procedimiento de esta manera:

```
public IActionResult Editar() { return View(); }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Editar(UsuariosCLS oUsuariosCLS)
        {
            try
            {
                string RPT = N_Cliente.Editar(Convert.ToInt32(oUsuariosCLS.ID_Cliente), 1, oUsuariosCLS.Name, oUsuariosCLS.LastName,
                            oUsuariosCLS.Mail, oUsuariosCLS.Age, oUsuariosCLS.Phone, oUsuariosCLS.Country, oUsuariosCLS.State_Departament,
                            oUsuariosCLS.Adress, oUsuariosCLS.Passport, oUsuariosCLS.DUI, oUsuariosCLS.User, oUsuariosCLS.Password);
                if (RPT=="OK")
                {
                    ViewBag.errorMessage = "Se edito";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.errorMessage = RPT;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                ViewBag.errorMessage = err.Message + "\n" + err.StackTrace;
                return View(oUsuariosCLS);
            }
            return View(oUsuariosCLS);
        }
```

De ahi lo he depurado y lo que veo que pasa es que al llegar al metodo Editar() inicia la coneccion, obtiene el command, pero luego de leer el codigo de primer parametro, pasa por parameter.Add(ParIDCliente) y salta hacia el Catch y suelta el error. He buscado dos semanas como resolverlo y no encuentro como. De antemano gracias!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christopher. Tú mismo acabas de dar con la respuesta a tu problema. Si te fijas, en la declaración de tus parámetros tienes lo siguiente:

```
 SqlParameter ParIDCliente = new SqlParameter();
 ParIDCliente.ParameterName = "@IDCliente";
 ParIDCliente.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
 ParIDCliente.Value = cliente.ID_Cliente;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(ParIDCliente); // ParIDCliente

 SqlParameter ParIDEmpleado = new SqlParameter();
 ParIDEmpleado.ParameterName = "@IDEmpleado";
 ParIDEmpleado.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
 ParIDEmpleado.Value = cliente.ID_Cliente;
 cmd.Parameters.Add(ParIDCliente); // Aquí debería ir ParIDEmpleado.
```

Estás añadiendo ParIDCliente dos veces, entonces, la colección de parámetros encuentra el parámetro `"IDCliente"` nuevamente y lanza la SQLException.

Como algo no tan relacionado, recuerda que puedes simplificar la inicializacion de tus objetos:

```
SqlParameter ParIDCliente = 
   new SqlParameter 
       {
        ParameterName = "@IDCliente",
        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
        Value = cliente.ID_Cliente
       };
cmd.Parameters.Add(ParIDCliente); // ParIDCliente
```

Es cuestión de gustos. Tal vez le encuentres el sabor.

Saludos.

Comment: Bueno, veo que he peliado semanas por un error de dedo. Agradezco la ayuda y por su puesto, ver otras maneras de hacer la cosas no va nada mal. Grecias!!!!!!